# WordPress - Theme options: Загрузка файлов/изображений

Tags: wordpress

Я создаю тему на WP и пишу для неё страницу настроек. Я хочу, чтобы пользователь мог изменять логотип сайта по нажатию на кнопку, которая открывает красивое окошко WordPress-a "Вставить медиафайл". Я нашёл какие-то отрывки инструкций в интернете и теперь у меня такой код (см. ниже).

В итоге, `admin.js` работает корректно, но когда я кликаю на "вставить запись" в диалоговом окне, получаю в консоль ошибку `document.getElementById(...) is null` в файле `load-scripts.php`. Думаю, я мог что-то напутать с порядком подключения файлов или пропустил какую-то зависимость. В WordPress я новичок :) Надеюсь на какие-нибудь подсказки, как это исправить или как это правильно реализовать.

functions.php

```
function true_include_myuploadscript() {
    if (!did_action('wp_enqueue_media')) {
        wp_enqueue_media();
    }

    wp_enqueue_script('myuploadscript', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/admin.js', ['jquery'], null, false);
}

function true_image_uploader_field($name, $value = '', $w = 757, $h = 265) {
    $default = get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/fenix_logo.png';

    if ($value) {
        $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src($value, [$w, $h]);
        $src = $image_attributes[0];
    } else {
        $src = $default;
    }?>

    <div>
        <img class="upload-image" data-src="<?php echo $default; ?>" src="<?php echo $src; ?>" width="<?php echo $w; ?>px" height="<?php echo $h; ?>px">
        <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $name; ?>" id="<?php echo $name; ?>" value="<?php echo $value; ?>">
        <button class="upload-image upload-image-btn">Загрузить</button>
        <button class="remove-image-btn">&times;</button>
    </div>

    <?php
}
```

... Пропускаю HTML-разметку самой странички настроек. В ней просто в середине вызывается функция следующим образом:

```
<?php if (function_exists('true_image_uploader_field')) {
                        true_image_uploader_field('phoenix_logo', get_option('phoenix_logo'));
} ?>
```

...

```
function setup_theme_admin_menu() {
    add_submenu_page(
        'themes.php',
        'Настройки внешнего вида темы',
        'Настройки темы',
        'manage_options',
        'theme_settings',
        'theme_options'
    );
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'setup_theme_admin_menu');
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'true_include_myuploadscript');
```

В самом верху подключается файл `admin.js` - вот его содержимое:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.upload-image').click(function() {
        var send_attachment_bkp = wp.media.editor.send.attachment;
        var parent = $(this).parent();

        wp.media.editor.send.attachment = function(props, attachment) {
            parent.children('.upload-image').attr('src', attachment.url);
            parent.children('input').val(attachment.id);

            wp.media.editor.send.attachment = send_attachment_bkp;
        };

        wp.media.editor.open(parent.children('.upload-image-button'));
        return false;
    });

    $('.remove-image-btn').click(function() {
        var parent = $(this).parent();

        if (confirm("Вы действительно хотите удалить это изображение?")) {
            var image = parent.children('.upload-image');

            image.attr('src', image.data('src'));
            parent.children('input').val('');
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Рекомендуемый ныне метод создания настроек - через кастомайзер, См  https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/

Comment: @SeVlad а я где-то видел, что этот метод пока уступает по функционалу страницам настроек. И поэтому пока что лучше использовать старый метод

Comment: ? Я даже не представляю что можно такого наваять, чтобы "уступал".

Comment: @SeVlad я попробую найти статью, в которой это говорилось как доказательство) По крайней мере, там говорилось, что кастомайзер не поддерживает редактор TinyMCE

Comment: Всё смешалось в доме Облонских.. Каким боком кастомайзер к TinyMCE? Никаким. А если нужно в кастомазере реализовать добавление контента через TinyMCE - с этим нет никаких проблем.